# What exactly does this dot mean in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, armasm

This is my ARM assembly code:

```
AREA MyData, DATA
V SPACE 4
N EQU .
```

I've noticed the next memory address, after the block reserved by SPACE, is stored in N thanks to EQU and the dot.

However, I haven't found any information about what exactly that dot is and what it does. Does anyone know what its "technical" name is?

Comment: The dot refers to the current address I think.

Comment: Like GAS syntax, I assume `.` means the current position, so it's basically equivalent to `N:` (defining N as a symbol with address = this position).  IDK if there's any subtle different between that and `N EQU .` in ARMASM, if they're even similar.  I assume this is ARMASM, since it's not GAS.